# Crear tabla editora sql server

Tags: php, html, sql-server

¿Me podríais explicar o pasar un código ejemplo de como hacer una tabla html editora en un php?.

Es decir hacer una consulta Sql reflejar los resultados en una tabla y en esa tabla poder editar todos los resultados y los cambios hechos que se guarden en la tabla sql.

Comment: Las preguntas amplias o colicitando código no son bien recibidas y terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega lo que lleves así como dudas puntuales